# How do I open a chest?

Tags: gemcraft-chasing-shadows

I noticed a selectable structure in one of my missions called a *Large Chest* that says I need to "Shoot with bolts 3 times to open".

What are bolts?  It's definitely not tower shots because I placed one nearby and targeted the chest and nothing happened.

How do I open it?

[image: Large Chest]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bolts are unlocked when you succeed level I3

Bolts is gem ehhancement.

With bolt, a gem ignores armor when the gem is located in a trap. The enhancement don't deplete when the gem is in a trap.

When the gem is located in a tower, you got a certain number of powershots.

To answer your question, the chest will open when you have a gem enhanced in a tower with bolts that shots it 3 times.

[image: bolts]

[More details here](https://gemcraft.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Fields_in_Gemcraft_Chapter_2)